# How to enforce hour format?

Tags: vb.net

I am using a textbox in vb.net but the input should be an hour format for example, "13h30".
How can I enfprce this by a user? When he puts the first 2 digits like 13 then automaticly the appl. puts a "h" between? Or is there a better solution?

thx

Comment: What type of application are you working on? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ...?

Comment: Use standard ISO8601 timeformat rather than tampering with custom crap.

Comment: @Michael-O, standard users want custom crap. Not many of them are familiar with the ISO8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms then you could use a `masked textbox` with a mask of `00h00`. This doesn't work too well if they subsequently want to edit the value they have entered though as the rightmost digits are shifted left if you do a backspace. You may be better off making a user control